# Grid Permutation Algorithm - Fixed Row Order

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, array-algorithms

Imagine a 3x3 grid:

```
[A, B, %]
[C, %, D]
[E, F, G]
```

The percentages `%` stand for empty spaces/positions.

The rows can be moved like beads on a string, such that the permutations for the configurations for the first row could be any one of:

```
[A, B, %] or [A, %, B] or [%, A, B]
```

Similarly for the second row. The third row contains no empty slots and so cannot change.

I am trying to produce all possible grids, given the possible permutations of each row.

The output should produce the following grids:

```
[A, B, %]    [A, B, %]    [A, B, %]
[C, D, %]    [C, %, D]    [%, C, D]
[E, F, G]    [E, F, G]    [E, F, G]

[A, %, B]    [A, %, B]    [A, %, B]
[C, D, %]    [C, %, D]    [%, C, D]
[E, F, G]    [E, F, G]    [E, F, G]

[%, A, B]    [%, A, B]    [%, A, B]
[C, D, %]    [C, %, D]    [%, C, D]
[E, F, G]    [E, F, G]    [E, F, G]
```

I have tried a method of looking through each row and shifting the space left and right, then generating new grids off that and recursing. I keep all grids in a set and ensure I only produce positions which haven't already been examined to prevent infinite recursion.

However, my algorithm seems to be horrendously inefficient (~1s per permutation!!) and doesn't look very nice either. I was wondering if there was an eloquent way of doing this? In python in particular.

I have some vague ideas but I'm sure there is a way of doing this which is short and simple which I'm overlooking.

**EDIT:** 3x3 is just an example. Grid could be of any size and it's really the row combinations which matter. For example:

```
[A, %, C]
[D, E, %, G]
[H, I]
```

is also a valid grid.

**EDIT 2:** The letters must maintain their order. For example `[A, %, B] != [B, %, A]` and `[B, A, %]` isn't valid

Comment: Does this need to work for arbitrary sized grids?

Comment: is ["A","B","%] considered to be != ["B","A","%"]?

Comment: The grid will be of arbitrary size, potentially each row could be different length also. 3x3 was just an example.

Comment: indeed, ["A","B","%] is considered to be != ["B","A","%"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get all desired permutations for each line. Then you calculate the cross product of all lines.

The permutations of a line can be simple calculated by having the letters [A,B,%] and varying the starting index:

```
import itertools
# Example: line = ['A','B','%']
def line_permutations(line):
   if '%' not in line:
       return [line]
   line.remove('%') # use copy.copy if you don't want to modify your matrix here
   return (line[:i] + ['%'] + line[i:] for i in range(len(line) + 1))
```

The cross product is easiest to achieve using itertools.product

```
matrix = [['A','B','%'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
permutations = itertools.product(*[line_permutations(line) for line in matrix])
for p in permutations:
    print(p)
```

This solution is optimal in memory and CPU requirements, because permutations are never recomputed.

Example output:

```
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', '%', 'B'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', '%', 'B'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', '%', 'B'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
```

Comment: I may have not understood you correctly, but just changing the starting index will not grant all the permutations. Although it would grant the desired solution.

Comment: Can you use a return with argument(s) statement inside a generator?

Comment: @NeXuS: See the OP "The rows can be moved like beads on a string"; I'll adapt this to make it clearer.

Comment: @Abhijit it's not a generator until you reach yield.

Comment: @j13r: Are you sure? Check the [result](http://ideone.com/cxs4o) from running this in Python 3.

Comment: @j13r: This was the only reason I have to write my generator (see my answer) in a peculiar way :-)

Comment: The A and B should always be in the same order. Will this algorithm obey this? Above you wrote ``['B', '%', 'A']`` which switches the order...?

Comment: This looks promising, will trial it out in my implementation and see how it compares to other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function called cycle

```
>>> def cycle(lst):
    while True:
        lst=lst[1:]+lst[0:1] if '%' in lst else lst
        yield lst
```

- Given an iterator, this will generate and return a cyclic left shift.
- Now you have to pass each of the rows in the grid to the cycle
  generator for the total iteration matching the length of the row
- Now use itertools.product to find all combinations of the generated
  row cyclic combinations.
- In case there is no empty slot, no cycle permutation is generated

The final result is as follows

```
>>> for g in list(itertools.product(*[[x for (x,y) in zip(cycle(row),
           range(0,len(row) if '%' in row else 1))] for row in grid])):
    for r in g:
        print r
    print "="*10
```

For your Grid, this will generate

```
['B', '%', 'A']
['%', 'D', 'C']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['B', '%', 'A']
['D', 'C', '%']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['B', '%', 'A']
['C', '%', 'D']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['%', 'A', 'B']
['%', 'D', 'C']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['%', 'A', 'B']
['D', 'C', '%']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['%', 'A', 'B']
['C', '%', 'D']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['A', 'B', '%']
['%', 'D', 'C']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['A', 'B', '%']
['D', 'C', '%']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
['A', 'B', '%']
['C', '%', 'D']
['E', 'F', 'G']
===============
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation:

```
g=[['A', 'B', '%'],
['C', '%', 'D'],
['E', 'F', 'G']]

from collections import deque
from itertools import product

def rotations(it):
    d = deque(it,len(it))
    for i in xrange(len(it)):
         d.rotate(1)
         yield list(d)

for i in product(*[rotations(x) if '%' in x else [x] for x in g]):
    print i
```

gives:

```
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['D', 'C', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['%', 'D', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['%', 'A', 'B'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['B', '%', 'A'], ['D', 'C', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['B', '%', 'A'], ['%', 'D', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['B', '%', 'A'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['D', 'C', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['%', 'D', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
(['A', 'B', '%'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox.py", line 2, in <module>
    ['C', '%', 'D']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Forgot to place the commas inside `g` :p

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Note that on one side this approach is less clean, but it allows you to compute the permutations of # len(matrix[0])-1 only once and use them as templates for the output.

```
from itertools import permutations,product

def charPermutation(matrix):
    permutation_list=list(permutations(["%%"]+["%s"]*(len(matrix[0])-1))) #Compute once, use infinitely
    perms={i:[] for i in range(len(matrix))}
    for it,line in enumerate(matrix):
        chars=list(set(line)-set(["%"]))
        if sorted(line)==sorted(chars):
            perms[it]+=["".join([str(i) for i in line])]
        else:
            for p in permutation_list:
                perms[it]+=["".join(["".join(p) % tuple(chars)])]
        perms[it]=list(set(perms[it]))
    return product(*[[list(k) for k in i] for i in perms.values()]) 

g=[
   ["A", "B", "%"],
   ["C", "%", "D"],
   ["E", "F", "G"]]

for x in charPermutation(g):
    print [i for i in x]

[['A', '%', 'B'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['A', '%', 'B'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['A', '%', 'B'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['%', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['%', 'A', 'B'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['%', 'A', 'B'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['A', 'B', '%'], ['C', 'D', '%'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['A', 'B', '%'], ['%', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
[['A', 'B', '%'], ['C', '%', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
```

Comment: What if the grid is of bigger size say 100*100? I think OP just gave a 3X3 grid as an example

Comment: I usually post just to make people understand what the reasoning is. Then it's better if they can implement what they really need (and if they can understand it). Anyhow it's trivial.

Comment: This output is accurate and what I need, but I'm not sure this can be scaled. I will edit the question to make it clear that a 3x3 was just an example.

Comment: And in the end.. puff! It scaled. :P

Comment: @PeterHamilton Can you perform a benchmark of this algo with a big matrix (> 15x15)?